# Material-UI List side by side React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make these lists in material UI in react go side by side. Can anyone help me?

```
<Typography><strong>Symptoms</strong></Typography>
        <ul>
            <h5>Common:</h5>
        <ul className="list">
            <li>Fever</li>
            <li>Tiredness</li>
            <li>Dry Cough</li>
        </ul>
        <h5 >Rare:</h5>
        <ul className="list">
            <li>Aches & Pains</li>
            <li>Nasal Congestion</li>
            <li>Runny Nose</li>
            <li>Sore Throat</li>
            <li>Diarrhoea</li>
        </ul>
        </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: You can solve this just with css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both in `Grid` container, and give each list 6 columns

---

```
<Grid container >
 <Grid item xs={6} >
        <h5>Common:</h5>
    <ul className="list">
        <li>Fever</li>
        <li>Tiredness</li>
        <li>Dry Cough</li>
    </ul>
  </Grid>
 <Grid item xs={6} >
    <h5 >Rare:</h5>
    <ul className="list">
        <li>Aches & Pains</li>
        <li>Nasal Congestion</li>
        <li>Runny Nose</li>
        <li>Sore Throat</li>
        <li>Diarrhoea</li>
    </ul>
    </Grid>
 </Grid>
```

---

read more - https://material-ui.com/components/grid/